# How to use react-navigation?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I have a typescript code. When I pressed to button of Transportations, navigation is not working. How to use react-navigation?

In the same directory, I have 'Transportations' folder with index.tsx file. In the index file, I exported by default some View's

```
<Content padder>
    <HomeItem
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Transportations")}
      icon="repeat"
      title={t("routes_transportations")}
    />
    <HomeItem
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Vaccination")}
      icon="medkit"
      title={t("routes_vacination")}
    />
    <HomeItem
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Sampling")}
      icon="color-filter"
      title={t("routes_sampling")}
    />
</Content>
```

Nothing will happened

Comment: But other navigation is working. This is the problem, that only Transportations is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have your screen in stack navigator or other react-navigation stacks,you should access navigation like `this.props.navigation.navigate()` in your components

Comment: I accessed in top of code. But in other navigation like Vaccination is working without `this.props...`

Comment: I do not  see your file where you create stack navigator . upload the file where you use createAppContainer & ... of react-navigation. I think it sholud be in App.js file